# "CMPL" -> Based mode into indirect addressing mode

Tags: assembly, x86, cmp, addressing

So I'm working on this file. I have to transform complex addressing mode into simple addressing mode.

I've managed to do

```
movl $0, 0(%esp)
```

into

```
addl $0, %esp
movl $0, (%esp)
addl $-0, %esp
```

works just fine, for all cases.

However I can't do the same thing with

```
cmpl $4, 28(%esp)
```

I understand that a compare is not the same as a move. 
But has anyone an idea how the simple version of the last line would look like?
Thx in advance

Comment: Note that `0(%esp)` and `(%esp)` mean the same thing (they result in exactly the same machine code sequences), so the two `addl`s are unnecessary in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same logic though:

```
movl %esp, %eax
addl $28, %eax
cmpl $4, (%eax)
```

Notice I used `eax` as temporary. You could move the stack pointer, but that's bad idea, and also it will mess up the flags when you try to restore it. You would need a temporary anyway, such as:

```
addl $28, %esp
movl (%esp), %eax
addl $-28, %esp
cmpl $4, %eax
```

You could of course use `lea` as that doesn't modify the flags, but you are apparently forbidden to use complex addressing mode. You can't use `pushf`/`popf` either, because those need the stack pointer.